# Most effective User-Agent Switcher Extension for Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, safari, datepicker

So I got stuck on my project for almost 2 days now. I am doing a cross-browser datepicker (vanilla js) targeting Safari browsers. I am using this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/dbclpoekepcmadpkeaelmhiheolhjflj?hl=en). I am using the Chrome browser and when I try to simulate a safari browser using the said extension, the datepicker seems to works fine. However, when I ask my friend to run the website online using the actual macbook, the styles seems to mess up. The question is:

> Do you know any extension that would deliver almost exactly the same as the actual safari browsers?

Would be glad to hear your recommendations. Expect some credits.

P.S. I dont have a macbook right now, so that complicates my situation. I also mainly do web development on my PC.

Comment: Why would a datepicker be dependent on User Agent?

Comment: You can use browserstack.com to test web software on different browsers.

Comment: @Barmar for example, the input type=date doesn't have a ui in safari browsers. What I do is detect if browser is safari, to load a special script for the datepicker.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the recommendation but for now I'm looking for an **extension** for the chrome or firefox browser

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is that it's not detecting that the browser is safari? What happens if you give your friend a version that's hard-coded to load the special script?

Comment: @Barmar it actually detects safari, the problem is when I compare the output using a simulated safari vs. the actual safari, it has a lot of differences that's why I'm looking for a browser user-agent switcher extension that has a higher output accuracy of what browser it imitates.

Comment: You think it's dependent on the Safari version? Often it's better to perform feature detection rather than trying to tailor to specific browsers, because you'll have to keep tweaking version checks.

Comment: Yes I have heard that kind of suggestion. As what I have mentioned in my question,  I do web development in my PC so I have to use a user agent switcher first to see the result before testing to actual browsers.

Comment: [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-singl/igafjdcboeahmnojhkaplghloibnjkbg/related?hl=en) allows you to specify the user agent string yourself, instead of just providing some canned user agents. Is that what you're looking for?